# Wrong prove for $L=\{a^m:m\geq 0,\; m \mod 3\neq 0\}$ isn't regular, but why?

Tags: automata, regular-language

First, let me just say that this language is regular, and I understand why.
But before I understood that, I tried proving that L isn't regular with pumping lemma. I just can't figure what is wrong with this prove:

let it be N>0 from the lemma, w=$a^m=xyz$, m>N.
We will mark |y|=k, |xz|=r ($k>0$, $r≥0$).
so w=$a^{k+r}$ and we also know that $a^{nk+r}$∈L, for all n≥0.

case 1- k mod 3=1, r mod 3=0: we will choose n=3 and get a contradiction to the lemma.

case 2- k mod 3=1, r mod 3=1: we will choose n=2 and get a contradiction.

case 3- k mod 3=2, r mod 3=0: we will choose n=3 and get a contradiction.

we got contradiction for every possible case of m mod 3=(k+r) mod 3≠0, and therefore condradicted the lemma.

Comment: What about $k \equiv r \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$?

Comment: But this is not a possible case. because if k mod 3=0, r mod 3=0, then $a^{k+r}$ doesn't belong to L. am I wrong?

Comment: Sloppy reading on my part, I thought the condition was $m \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. It's $m \not\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ in fact. Not a big deal, you consider $k \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and $r \not\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. Whenever your word has at least five characters, you can split and pump, $a(aaa)a\dotsc$.

Comment: All you know is that $w=a^m = xyz = a^sa^ka^t$ for some $k>0$ and $s,t\ge 0$, where your $r = s+t$, and that for all $n$, $w_n = a^sa^{nk}a^t \in L$. But $a_n = a^{s+t}a^{nk} = wa^{(n-1)k}$. So $|w_n | = m + (n-1)k$. Thus if $k =3$, or $k=6$, or... then $|w| \equiv |w_n| \pmod 3$.

Comment: Since you understand why $L$ is regular and since the pumping lemma has a constructive proof, you might find it instructive to apply that proof to this specific $L$ and see exactly what ends up getting pumped.

Answer (score 1):

To see that $L$ is regular, consider the DFA $M=(Q,\Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$ where $Q=\{0,1,2\}$, $\Sigma=\{a\}$, $q_0=0$, $F=\{1,2\}$, and transition function
$$\delta(n,a) = \delta(n+1,a),$$
with $n\bmod 3$, or equivalently, the regular expression
$$(a\cup aa)(aaa)^*.$$